# Add folder to classpath

Tags: java

I have a the following source structure

```
/src/main/java
/src/main/resources
/src/main/resources/stuff
/src/main/resources/stuff/1.txt
/src/main/resources/stuff/2.txt
```

In my code I access the files in the stuff folder via:

```
ClassLoader.class.getResource("/stuff/1.txt").getFile()
```

When this is deployed it is deployed like this:

```
/
/lib
/lib/my-app.jar
/lib/other.jar
/lib/stuff
```

Currently my classpath is set to: `lib/*` but I can't resolve `lib/stuff/1.txt` in the way I do above. What do I need to set on the classpath for the above code to work?

Comment: too vague. This seems to be a Maven project based on the directory structure. How is your application packaged? How is it deployed? How is it executed? And why use getResource().getFile() and not just use the 100% portable getResourceAsStream() ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the difference between using relative and absolute paths as pointed out in [this blog](http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/java/system/java-resource-loading-explained-absolute-and-relative-names-difference-between-classloader-and-class-resource-loading).

```
ClassLoader.class.getResource("lib/stuff/1.txt").getFile()
```

As pointed out by @Gimby, it'd be more efficient to use `getResourseAsStream()`.